# Is there something like `SET UPDATE TASK LOCAL` for `CALL FUNCTION ... STARTING NEW TASK`?

Tags: abap

In order to force `CALL FUNCTION ... IN UPDATE TASK` to be executed synchronosuly in the same LUW after `COMMIT WORK` there is a nice ABAP command `SET UPDATE TASK LOCAL`.

Is there something similar for `CALL FUNCTION ... STARTING NEW TASK`?

Background: I want to test some coding which I cannot change using database mocking with `CL_OSQL_TEST_ENVIRONMENT`. Unfortunately the instance of the test environment is only available in the current LUW when executing unit tests. If there is an asynchronous function module call then all the database accesses go to the database directly because the test environment is no longer valid in another LUW.

Comment: Short answer: I dont think there is. `STARTING NEW TASK` opens a completly new session. So there would be no way to have the instance of the test environment there. To execute the function locally you would have to remove the `STARTING NEW TASK`, running the function synchronously as well. That would basically be the same as `SET UPDATE TASK LOCAL` since `COMMIT WORK` (in this case) runs the update task synchronously too.